# AutonomyLab Ardrone wind_comp_angle

Tags: ros, ardrone, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

Can anybody help me how to use and what exactly does this wind comp angle represent.

I'm having problem when issuing command to change height only. It often happens that the drone drifts away because of the wind. Drone does not stabilize itself.
I guess that I should use wind_comp_angle to compensate for that wind, to stabilize the drone.

Thank's for help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62441/autonomylab-ardrone-wind_comp_angle/) by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2013-05-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2013-07-10**:
Hi, did you get what exactly means the wind compensation angle? I am interested this issue too.

**Comment by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on 2013-07-14**:
Hey. In my experience and testing wind compensation angle is the speed that should compensate the wind. I used with the ArDrone SDK like this:

**Comment by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on 2013-07-14**:
ardrone_tool_set_progressive_cmd(4,current_comp_phi/euler_angle_max, current_comp_theta/euler_angle_max, 0, 0, 0, 0.0)

I guess it should work the same with AutonomyLab drivers. I normalized wind speed with the maximum euler angles seted up in the config.

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2013-07-14**:
Hi. Thank you very much! Have you tried to stabilize the AR.Drone over definite position by AutonomyLab?

**Comment by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on 2013-07-15**:
I did try to stabilize. First with PID and oriented cocarde detection with the help of these instructions: http://www.ludep.com/category/drone/.
It was so so successful. I needed very good stabilization so I switched to ardrone embedded hover_over_roundel flying mode which works way better.

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2013-07-15**:
Hi. Thank you for link. It is very helpful for me.  I have tried to stabilize by PID too. However I got off the position about 1.2 m. But guys from TUM had a deviation only 0.6 m (http://vision.in.tum.de/_media/teaching/ss2013/visnav2013/sheet3_solution.pdf). What deviation did you have?

**Comment by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on 2013-07-15**:
I did stabilization over a fixed point on the ground. I guess you try to fly drone to the point in space, I didn't try that because of the large amount of IMU error. I guess some error should be reduced using Kalman filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you very much. I will try to turn off the stabilization of altitude.

---

Originally posted by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) with karma: 641 on 2013-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0